# Do S-Corps and C-Corps both end their business names in "Corp"?

Tags: business

I plan on starting my second company as a corporation and filing as an S-Corp. Would my new business name still be

> Business Name Corporation

or is a different form used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no distinction in the name of an entity based upon whether it is an S-corporation or a C-corporation.

Corporation, Incorporated, Inc., Limited and Ltd. are often allowed a corporation designators under state incorporation statutes.

Also, it is possible to elect to have a limited liability company or other limited liability entity such as a limited liability partnership, limited liability limited partnership or limited partnership association taxed as either a C-corporation or as an S-Corporation, in which case the appropriate designator for those types of entities could also be used.

In general, the state law entity type usually does not establish the nature of the entity for tax purposes if the entity has limited liability.